# Convert string with date and string with time in single Date in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a date and a time stored in different strings in Typescript and I want to convert that into a Date.

It's driving me nuts because I'm in GMT-3 and the date is not what it should even though I'm using UTC.

I have 2 concerns: 1st, the date is not correct, and 2nd, is there a more "elegant" way to do this?

```
   parseDate(date: string, time: string) : Date {
        let d = new Date(Date.UTC(
          Number(date.substring(0,4)), 
          Number(date.substring(5,7)) - 1, 
          Number(date.substring(8)),
          Number(time.substring(0, 2)),
          Number(time.substring(3))
        ));
        return d;
      }
```

I'm testing with date '2018-02-09' and time '10:15' and I get Thu Feb 09 2018 07:15:00 GMT-0300 (SA Eastern Standard Time)

Answer (score 2):

When using Date.UTC you are setting the Timezone to UTC, to use the browser timezone, you can simply use:

```
parseDate(date: string, time: string) : Date {
  return new Date(date + ' ' + time)
}
parseDate('2018-02-09', '10:15') // Fri Feb 09 2018 10:15:00 GMT+0100 (CET) - I'm in GMT+01
```

Answer (score 1):

That date actually looks fine, are you using toString() to see what it contains? That would always use your local timezone.

Try with toUTCString()

if you require nice parsing capabilities without importing a completely bloated library, I would advise fecha (https://github.com/taylorhakes/fecha)

Comment: sorry, I misstyped the date, it's corrected now; anyway, it does not look fine, the time is 07:15 and it should be 10:15; if I don´t use UTC then the date is 08 when it should be 09.
I check the date using the console, because I want to use it as a Date and not as a String

Comment: Try console.log(date.toUTCString())  ?